# <unresolved overloaded function type> with member function pointer and templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pointer-to-member

sorry for my problem to be somewhat complicated, here it is:

I have an helper struct that hold any non-type template parameter that is declared like this:

```
template<typename T, T t>
struct Method {
    using Type = T;
    constexpr static T method = t;
};
```

I'm using it to store a member function pointer to use at compile-time.

Then, I have a class called `TestClass` that has a typedef to the `Method` type with one of it's method as parameter:

```
struct TestClass {
    void setFoo(int n) {}

    using MethodToCall = Method<decltype(&TestClass::setFoo), &TestClass::setFoo>;
};
```

Everything is okay at this point, and I can call it like this:

```
(tc.*TestClass::MethodToCall::method)(6); // compiles and runs
```

Then, there is the problem: I have another member function that takes a method as a template parameter again, and I'm trying to get a pointer from it. It works only If I put the function pointers directly.

```
struct Caller {
    template<typename T, T t>
    void callme(TestClass& test) {
        (test.*t)(6);
    }
};

template<typename F, typename T, typename... Args>
auto call(F f, T t, Args&&... args) -> decltype((t.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
    (t.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    Caller c;
    TestClass tc;

    (tc.*TestClass::MethodToCall::method)(6);

    //call(&Caller::callme<TestClass::MethodToCall::Type, TestClass::MethodToCall::method>, c, tc);
    call(&Caller::callme<decltype(&TestClass::setFoo), &TestClass::setFoo>, c, tc);

    return 0;
}
```

The three first call won't work. Why is this? How can I fix it?
If I uncomment the first call, the compile gives me this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:40:96: error: no matching function for call to 'call(<unresolved overloaded function type>, Caller&, TestClass&)'
     call(&Caller::callme<TestClass::MethodToCall::Type, TestClass::MethodToCall::method>, c, tc);
                                                                                                ^
main.cpp:30:6: note: candidate: template<class F, class T, class ... Args> decltype (call::t.*call::f((forward<Args>)(call::args)...)) call(F, T, Args&& ...)
 auto call(F f, T t, Args&&... args) -> decltype((t.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
      ^
main.cpp:30:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:40:96: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'F'
     call(&Caller::callme<TestClass::MethodToCall::Type, TestClass::MethodToCall::method>, c, tc);
                                                                                                ^
```

The full code can be found here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/821c5b874b45ffb9

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that `Method` is mostly `std::integral_constant`.
For the second commented line, you have to remove `const` : `std::remove_const_t<decltype(TestClass::MethodToCall::method)>`.

Comment: The other errors can be reduce to [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f78b09dc2924fa9) ( *"invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter t"*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake. You can't send a member function pointer to a template parameter that is stored in a variable, even a `constexpr` one.

```
constexpr auto theMethod = &TestClass::setFoo;

// won't work
call(&Caller::callme<decltype(theMethod), theMethod>);
```

In a template parameter that is a member function pointer, it is required that it is wrote directly:

```
constexpr auto theMethod = &TestClass::setFoo;

// won't work
call(&Caller::callme<decltype(theMethod), &TestClass::setFoo>);
```

My solution was to pass around an `std::integral_constant` instead of the function pointer directly.

```
using methodType = std::integral_constant<decltype(&TestClass::setFoo), &TestClass::setFoo>;

call(&Caller::callme<methodType>);
```